# jQuery form submit not functioning while selecting via class or id

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the following HTML and jQuery

```
<form class='tform' method='post' action='/ajax/process'>
       ..........
<button type = 'submit'>submit</button>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.tform').bind('submit', function(e) {


                alert(8);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
});
```

While using class even if I use live or bind it doesn't seem to work. However, if I use $('form') while using either live or bind, it works. The problem is I want to use class.

Thanks guys.

Comment: [Use `.on()` instead for latest versions of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Comment: Any error in console? Please check once.

Comment: I wonder if the typo of `buttom` instead of `button` matters.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/8bNTe/  Fixed syntax error in button to send submit event.

Comment: dosent mate , just checked and changed to input

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/c54Vn/ (note the miss-spelled `buttom` in your code though)

Comment: oh that , nah it still dosent work...soz for the spelling lol

Comment: Yes, it does work. There must be an error elsewhere in your logic/code.

Comment: well that form is within a table , does that matter in a way ?

Answer (score 1):

Please make your HTML markup correct and try again:

```
<button type='submit'>submit</button>
```

Not this:

```
<buttom type = 'submit'>submit</buttom>
```